# Cannot delete from UDF partition (SSD)

Tags: mount, filesystem, fstab, udf

I have Xubuntu 16.10 and I dual boot with Windows 10.  I have a secondary SSD drive and wanted to choose a somewhat OS-agnostic filesystem for it so I can use it both Windows and Linux, and after doing some research, I decided to try UDF.

I have added the following entry to /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sda2 /mnt/e_drive udf   defaults,uid=1000,rw 0 0
```

It seems to be mounted as it should be:

```
adam@BC-LINPC-02:/$ mount |grep e_drive
/dev/sda2 on /mnt/e_drive type udf (rw,relatime,uid=1000,utf8)
```

I can add new files, and it seems I can delete those new files:

```
adam@BC-LINPC-02:/mnt/e_drive/src/project_test$ echo "hello world" > some_new_file.txt
adam@BC-LINPC-02:/mnt/e_drive/src/project_test$ ls -lah some_new_file.txt 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 adam adam 12 Jan  6 03:14 some_new_file.txt
adam@BC-LINPC-02:/mnt/e_drive/src/project_test$ rm -fr some_new_file.txt
```

However, I can't seem to delete any existing files or directories:

```
adam@BC-LINPC-02:/mnt/e_drive/src/project_test$ sudo rm -fr dist.7z 
rm: cannot remove 'dist.7z': Operation not permitted
adam@BC-LINPC-02:/mnt/e_drive/src/project_test$ ls -lah dist.7z
-rwxrwxrwx 1 adam nogroup 788K Dec 29 05:07 dist.7z
```

Is there anything I can do to make this work?  Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

UPDATE:

In response to George's comment, I should have mentioned that chown doesn't work either:

```
adam@BC-LINPC-02:/mnt/e_drive/src/project_test$ sudo chown -Rv adam:adam .tmp
[sudo] password for adam: 
chown: changing ownership of '.tmp/templateCache.js': Operation not permitted
failed to change ownership of '.tmp/templateCache.js' from adam:nogroup to adam:adam
chown: changing ownership of '.tmp/concat/scripts/scripts.js': Operation not permitted
failed to change ownership of '.tmp/concat/scripts/scripts.js' from adam:nogroup to adam:adam
chown: changing ownership of '.tmp/concat/scripts/vendor.js': Operation not permitted
failed to change ownership of '.tmp/concat/scripts/vendor.js' from adam:nogroup to adam:adam
chown: changing ownership of '.tmp/concat/scripts': Operation not permitted
failed to change ownership of '.tmp/concat/scripts' from adam:nogroup to adam:adam
chown: changing ownership of '.tmp/concat': Operation not permitted
failed to change ownership of '.tmp/concat' from adam:nogroup to adam:adam
chown: changing ownership of '.tmp/scripts/app.d.ts': Operation not permitted
failed to change ownership of '.tmp/scripts/app.d.ts' from adam:nogroup to adam:adam
...  (every file in that recursive tree) ...
```

Comment: Try changing the group ownership .

Comment: UDF is interesting, but unfortunately I think it is neither maintained nor developed.  For example, I think there are no tools to repair it, if damaged. (I would be happy, if someone could show that I am wrong.) Instead, I would recommend NTFS if you want to share a data partition between Ubuntu and Windows.